# Size of Blob created from Uint8Array gives nonsense values

Tags: javascript, blob, typed-arrays, uint8array

So I was wondering why this `Blob` object has a `size` of 5:

```js
var x = new Uint8Array(2);
x[0] = 255;
x[1] = 10;
console.log("Typed array length is " + x.length + ".")
console.log("Typed array byte length is " + x.byteLength + ".")
console.log("Blob size is " + new Blob(x).size + ' "bytes".')
```

For me it makes no sense, because an `Uint8Array` element can be stored inside a byte. (`Uint8Array` items can handle a value from 0 to 255.)

Also, changing `x[0]` or `x[1]` seems to change `new Blob(x).size`. `x.byteLength`, however, gives the expected result to me.

I can't find any explanation for this, even though I've searched everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Blob` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) takes an array of buffers, not a single buffer. Your current code works the same as

```
new Blob(["255", "10"])
```

which is why you get a size of `5`. You would need to write

```
var x = new Uint8Array([255, 10]);
new Blob([x])
//       ^ ^
```

Comment: You need to pass an array of `Uint8Array`s.